# Replace certain number of numbers with continuous occurrence with some value from top to bottom equally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1    col2
  1      A
  2      B
  3      B
  4      B
  5      B
  6      C
  7      A
  8      A
  9      A
  10     A
  11     B
  12     C
```

Now I want to create a data frame from above data frame in a condition if continuous occurrence of a any value in col2 is 4(lets say n1) replace two (lets say n2) values (one from top and one from bottom) of those with any value lets say ('D')

I want to create a function lets say f(df,n1,n2,'D'), and this will return following data frame,

```
col1    col2
  1      A
  2      D
  3      B
  4      B
  5      D
  6      C
  7      D
  8      A
  9      A
  10     D
  11     B
  12     C
```

I can do it using a for loop, but the execution time will be huge, I am looking for pandas shortcut/ pythonic way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution working if no missing values in `col2` column:

```
def f(df, n1, n2, val):

    #count consecutive values of col2
    s = df.groupby(df['col2'].ne(df['col2'].shift()).cumsum())['col2'].transform('size')

    #compare by threshold and create missing values, with forward and back replacement
    m1 = s >= n1
    m2 = df['col2'].mask(m1).ffill(limit=n2).bfill(limit=n2).notna()

    #chain masks and set val
    df['col2'] = df['col2'].mask(m1 & m2, val)
    return df

df1 = f(df,4,1,'D')

print (df1)
    col1 col2
0      1    A
1      2    D
2      3    B
3      4    B
4      5    D
5      6    C
6      7    D
7      8    A
8      9    A
9     10    D
10    11    B
11    12    C
```

If possible some missing values is necessary replace them by some value:

```
def f(df, n1, n2, val):

    a = df['col2'].fillna('tmp')

    s = a.groupby(a.ne(a.shift()).cumsum()).transform('size')

    m1 = s >= n1
    m2 = a.mask(m1).ffill(limit=n2).bfill(limit=n2).notna()

    df['col2'] = df['col2'].mask(m1 & m2, val)
    return df
```